# iOS incorrect width and height

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

First of all, I'm new to iOS. 
Recently I try to make some games with spritekit, but no matter how I tried, I just can't get the size right.
The problem is that, I did not change the orientation settings, but when I printed out the self.size, the width is 1024 and the height is 768, and this causes a disaster that first, my background image is stretched according to landscape dimension but is showed in portrait; and second, CGPointZero (coordinate (0,0)) is actually outside the screen instead of the lower left corner of the screen. (so when I try to add edges they are actually not within the screen, which gives me a headache)
I wonder why that happened.

And I noticed that the initWithSize method which used to be in iOS7 is not in iOS8 auto-generated template any more, and instead there is a didMoveToView. So is it correct to assume we can start doing stuff in this method?

Comment: If your scene is being loaded from an .sks file then change the size of the scene in that file. You can still used init(size:) if you don't want to load your scene from an .sks file

Comment: most SK devs run the first scene from viewWillLayoutSubviews because of the dimension mixup, so look that up and give it a try. Next, if you position a sprite at 0,0 then only its top-right quarter will be on screen - this is normal since the sprite defaults to center on the position. You can change the anchor point of the sprite to 0,0 but it's generally recommended not to do that and instead set the position to half width/height of the sprite instead (anchor point is also center of scale/rotate operations so it's best to leave it alone for gameplay sprites).

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I just found the solution!
I think the size I'm actually referring to is the scene size, which in xcode 6 is by default determined by GameScene.sks file.
The reason of the incorrect size is that, we can see in this file scene size is initially set to 1024(width) * 768 (height). That leads to the scene shown in landscape mode even though the actually orientation is portrait.
All I need to do is to manually change the 1024 * 768 to 768 * 1024 (or 320*568 for a 4-inch iphone).